# How to run the the latest cli version of Monero?

Tags: command-line, apt, snap, flatpak, bitcoin

How would I install [v18](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/wmtrs8/cli_gui_v01810_fluorine_fermi_ledger_monero_app/) of the `cli` monero [wallet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13957/14165)?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo apt install monero
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
monero is already the newest version (0.17.2.0+~0+20200826-1ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 306 not upgraded.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ monerod --version
Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-unknown)
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ flatpak info org.getmonero.Monero

Monero GUI - Monero: the secure, private, untraceable cryptocurrency

          ID: org.getmonero.Monero
         Ref: app/org.getmonero.Monero/x86_64/stable
        Arch: x86_64
      Branch: stable
     Version: 0.18.2.2
     License: BSD-3-Clause
      Origin: flathub
  Collection: org.flathub.Stable
Installation: system
   Installed: 140.9 MB
     Runtime: org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-22.08
         Sdk: org.kde.Sdk/x86_64/5.15-22.08

      Commit: e12002e9ff82c6446a107fb31fa5db3ddf93e8b38251f6e288b04db7c472c3b6
      Parent: 9597733eb5c8b8de1d1a0a239c654c5da6dddc15a3bc757874c15903daddf06f
     Subject: build: Update p2pool to 3.3 (96939ce0)
        Date: 2023-05-01 04:44:03 +0000
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

which relates to a [hard fork](https://www.getmonero.org/2020/08/18/network-upgrade-october-2020.html) within `XMR` necessitating v18.  The `CLI` version doesn't show `Fluorine Fermi` but is on, as above, `Oxygen Orion` and so won't show new transactions. The `GUI`, originating from `Flatpak`, is updated.

Comment: See https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/monero : The v0.18 package in Debian has a lot of problems and fails to build. Then see [LP:1806609](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/monero/+bug/1806609): Fails to build in the Ubuntu build farm. When a volunteer fixes those various bugs, then you can install v0.18

Comment: that explains it @user535733 but it's interesting that the GUI does install, albeit on flatpak.  Thx.